# Cant initialize GLew with GLFW3

Tags: c++, opengl, initialization, glew, glfw

I'm trying to initialize ***GLew 1.10*** along with the latest version of ***GLFW3.*** I've managed to get GLFW3 to work without a problem, but GLew is being quite difficult. I followed the example from the GLew website on how to initialize, but `glewInit()` for some reason is undefined and `glewGetContext identifier not found / undefined` (errors at bottom):

```
#include <GLew110\glew.h>
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLU
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    fputs(description, stderr);
}
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}
int main(void)
{   
    GLFWwindow* window;
    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);
    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Simple example", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    GLenum err = glewInit(); // <---- "glewGetContext" is undefined (line 29)
    if (GLEW_OK != err)
    {
        /* Problem: glewInit failed, something is seriously wrong. */
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));

    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        float ratio;
        int width, height;
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        ratio = width / (float) height;
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(-ratio, ratio, -1.f, 1.f, 1.f, -1.f);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glRotatef((float) glfwGetTime() * 50.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor3f(1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
        glVertex3f(-0.6f, -0.4f, 0.f);
        glColor3f(0.f, 1.f, 0.f);
        glVertex3f(0.6f, -0.4f, 0.f);
        glColor3f(0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
        glVertex3f(0.f, 0.6f, 0.f);
        glEnd();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**TWO ERRORS LISTED:**

```
error C3861: 'glewGetContext': identifier not found (line 29 pointing to glewInit())
IntelliSense: identifier "glewGetContext" is undefined (line 29)
```

Comment: This sounds like a compile/link problem, but that's not 100% clear from the question.  Please post a complete, small sample program that shows the problem (it sounds like a program with nothing but a `glewInit()` call would do the trick), and copy/paste the exact error message(s).

Comment: @MichaelBurr thanks for the reply. I've updated the code (runnable) and listed the two errors I received at the bottom. removing the code that suppose to initialize GLew will show a rotating colored triangle.

Comment: glewinit should be after glfwMakeCurrentContext

Comment: On a side comment: Please do not use backslashes `'\'` in include directives.

Answer (score 1):

Something is defining the macro `GLEW_MX` which is used to configure the `glew` library for multiple rendering contexts.  Building with such a configuration requires some special preparation.  The following is from http://glew.sourceforge.net/advanced.html (emphasis added):

> Multiple Rendering Contexts (GLEW MX)
>
> Starting with release 1.2.0, thread-safe support for multiple
>   rendering contexts, possibly with different capabilities, is
>   available. Since this is not required by most users, it is not added
>   to the binary releases to maintain compatibility between different
>   versions. To include multi-context support, you have to do the
>   following:
>
> - Compile and use GLEW with the GLEW_MX preprocessor token defined.
> - For each rendering context, create a GLEWContext object that will be available as long as the rendering context exists.
> - **Define a macro or function called glewGetContext()** that returns a pointer to the GLEWContext object associated with the rendering
>     context from which OpenGL/WGL/GLX calls are issued. This dispatch
>     mechanism is primitive, but generic.
> - **Make sure that you call glewInit() after creating the GLEWContext object** in each rendering context. Note, that the GLEWContext pointer
>     returned by glewGetContext() has to reside in global or thread-local
>     memory.

If you don't need multiple rendering contexts, the best thing might be to find out where `GLEW_MX` is being set and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone has similar issue.
Please try to call glewInit after calling glfwMakeContextCurrent :)

```
/* Make the window's context current */
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
int glewErr = glewInit();
```